# How to transform one string to another with minimal number of edits?

Tags: java, string, algorithm

I was asked this question during phone interview.

Given two strings find the minimal number of edits required in order to transform one string to another. The solution needs to be implemented in java and run in O(n*m), assuming that n and m are the lengths of the input strings.

*Example:*
strings:   **milk** -> **beer**
min edits: **4**

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance

Comment: This is what you want: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance Edit: Mchl beat me to it :/

Comment: or this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_distance

Comment: @mindandmedia Hammering distance doesn't consider edits/deletions.

Comment: oh ok, but then the example is bad, because n=m (edits yes, not deletions, inserts)

Comment: The answer isn't 4 but 1. Without defining what an edit is, my solution is as good as anyone else's.

Comment: @mindandmedia No, the example isn't necessarily bad, but you should mention that the Hamming Distance doesn't consider insertions. Perhaps the OP just wanted Hamming Distance, but it is also possible that the OP wants Levenshtein Distance.

Comment: @Ryan Amos, thanks! would you mind to post your comment as an answer so i could accept it?

Comment: @aviad Done. I added some more information that might be helpful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For strings of the different length, use the Levenshtein Distance:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance

If you have strings of equal length and you do not want to consider insertions or deletions, the Hamming Distance is more efficient:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_distance

Example implementations of Levenshtein distance:
http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Algorithm_Implementation/Strings/Levenshtein_distance

Answer (score 0):

Assumption:Word contains distinct letters.

How about creating Character Hashset for S1.

Now iterate through each character in S2 and try to remove it from Hashset of S1. If you can remove the character, dont increment the counter. else increment the counter.

The counter contains the minimum number of edits.